# Unable to convert (int*) to int

Tags: c, arrays

I'm just trying to read the elements from a text file that has all the numbers and pass it as an argument to the "frequency()" function given below.However,It shows up an error saying that 
"argument of type int is incompatible with argument of type (int*)" . I tried everything to convert (int*) to int but ended up miserably..below posted is my C code.

```
  void main()
     {
    FILE*file = fopen("num.txt","r");
    int integers[100];
    int i=0;
    int h[100];
    int num;
    int theArray[100];
    int n,k;
    int g;
   int x,l;
    while(fscanf(file,"%d",&num)>0)
   {
      integers[i]=num;
     k =(int)integers[i];

    printf("%d\n",k);

      i++;
   }


  printf ("\n OK, Thanks! Now What Number Do You Want To Search For Frequency In Your Array? ");

   scanf("\n%d", &x);/*Stores Number To Search For Frequency*/

      frequency(k,n,x);
      getch();
      fclose(file); 

    }


void  frequency (int theArray [ ], int n, int x)
 {
  int count = 0;
 int u;
//  printf("%d",n);


  for (u = 0; u < n; u++)
   {
    if ( theArray[u]==x)
    {
        count = count + 1 ;
        /*printf("\n%d",theArray[u]);*/
    /*  printf("\n%d",count);*/


    }      
    else
    {
        count = count ;
    } 
     }

     printf ("\nThe frequency of %d in your array is %d ",x,count);


  }
```

So the idea is that the  elements read through "num.txt" are stored in an array 'k' and the same array has to be passed in the frequency function! However,in my case it is saying "argument of type int is incompatible with argument of type(int*).

Comment: You are passing `int` to `int[]`. I think you should pass `integers` to it.

Comment: Don't use `void main()` in general — see [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336) for more information.

Comment: This cast `k =(int)integers[i];` is worrying.  It isn't necessary to convert an `int` to an `int` with a cast — so why did you add the cast and what don't you understand that made you think the cast was a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 frequency(k,      n,       x);
           |
           |
           +---int ?
```

But

```
frequency (int theArray [ ], int n, int x) 
                     |
                     |
                     + accepts an int*
```

Call your function as

```
frequency ( integers, i, x );
```

You never initialized `n` and `theArray` in your main, simply declaring them will not *magically* pass them in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `frequency` function, you're passing in the `int` `k` as the first argument. I think it's worth correcting your statement that `k` is an array.  It is not.  You declare it as an `int`. This is where your type error is coming from because it expects an `int *` (because of the `int[]` argument).

Perhaps you mean to pass in `integers` instead of `k`?

Comment: this is fine i'm trying to  print the elements that  integers stored ..However i'm getting something like 1375076.So,if i want to get the elements stored in the array integers what am i supposed to   do?